# Visual Studio 2010 Exceptions checking extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I'm looking for some way to make a VS editor highlight methods that throws an exception. I've looked around for some add-in, but I haven't found any suitable.

So I've been looking for some tutorials describing how to make my own add-in. I found many tutorials showing how to underline text, modify tooltip and so on, but I haven't found any tutorial that shows how to access a documentation of specific method.

I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: How would you tell whether a method could throw an exception or not? Bear in mind that one method which doesn't *directly* throw an exception may well call a method which *does* throw the exception...

Comment: @Jon Simple, write a method to figure it out for called methods, and run it recursively. ;)

Comment: I'll take a stab in the dark that the user is adding `/// <exception cref="SomeException">when things go wrong.</exception>` type documentation to their methods and wants their extension to read these.

Comment: Are you trying to find something that emulates Java? The C# documentation syntax does allow the listing of exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Well, kinda. I really like the fact, that in Java there's no way to forget to not process a exception. I know Java uses checked exceptions and C# doesn't... But whatever, it does not mean it can not be programmed using the documentation tags.

Comment: @JonSkeet Mmm, yes, that might be a big performance problem. Browse through all the nested functions could take a really long time, but now it is not decisive. After all, this would be changed from real-time highlight to a analytical check tool. Who knows.

Comment: @JiříTravěnec: How much do you trust those documentation tags?

Answer (score 2):

You can use information provided by IntelliSense:

[image]

You can provide exception list to IntelliSence via xml comments to your methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Foos every bar.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"/>
public static void Foo()
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: Yes, know that. I'm looking for something more intuitive. Thought that using the same functionality as IntelliSence does and combinating it with some tutorial showing how to highlight text might produce useful result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VS debugger to follow the code or use breakpoints to run a macro that will highlight lines (not sure this will york properly because you have to apply them at some crucial points)

Answer (score 0):

You also can set Exception settings of VS (Ctrl-Shift-E) to stop immediately on exception thrown. That will cease execution on method that caused exception and put cursor on it.